# silverlight grid background image

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How do you set the backgound image of a grid in c# (code behind).

Thanks
Sp
Can I do something like this?

```
    public ImageSource ImageSourcePin
{
    set { this.DreamTypeImagePin.Background = value; }
}
```

This worked,thanks for your help

```
        public String ImageSourcePin
    {
        set {
            ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
            img.ImageSource = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(value); 
            DreamTypeImagePin.Background = img;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want XAML to codebehind conversion. You can try this. http://xamlt.com/ This could be handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
    img.ImageSource = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Image.jpg");
    System.Windows.Controls.Grid g = new System.Windows.Controls.Grid();
    g.Background = img;

HTH

Answer (score 11):

Try using an `ImageBrush`. Place this inbetween your `<Grid>` and `</Grid>` tags.

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image.jpg"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Imperatively, you could write this as:

```
ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"folder\img.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
grid.Background = imgBrush;
```